# Combo Box JavaFx with FXML

Tags: combobox, javafx-2, javafx, fxml

how can i use to **Combo Box** with **FXML**? i need to set dynamic data.. Does anyone have an example?

This is my Sample.fxml

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="javafxapplication15.SampleController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
        <ComboBox  fx:id="ciudad" prefWidth="123.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">                
            <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="firstName" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </ComboBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Please look up Oracle documentation.

Comment: how can i do match with the properties of Model class?? for example the TableView need <Columns> <TableColumn> <CellValueProperty> <PropertyValueFactory property="name"> how i do with Combo Box?

Comment: Give it an observable list in your controller code. http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/combo-box.htm#BABJCCIB

Comment: @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        prueba = FXCollections.observableArrayList();     
        ciudad.setItems(prueba);
        prueba.add(new Person("Maria", "Perez", null));
        prueba.add(new Person("Luis", "Pinto", null));
    }

Comment: i need only the "FirstName" on combo box..

Comment: Give it the first name string then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See this [JavaFX FXML ComboBox demo app](https://gist.github.com/3062859).  For dynamic data you can either dynamically generate your fxml using something like [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or, probably better, populate an ObservableList and provide it to your fxml injected ComboBox instance.

Here is a modified version of the demo app which populates the ObservableList of ComboBox items in the controller initializer.

*fruitcombo.css*

```
/** fruitcombo.css
place in same directory as FruitComboApplication.java
ensure build system copies the css file to the build output path */

.layout {
  -fx-background-color: cornsilk;
}

#selected-fruit-frame {
  -fx-border-color: burlywood;
  -fx-border-width: 5;
  -fx-background-color: white;
}

.bold-label {
  -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

*fruitcombo.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- fruitcombo.fxml
     place in same directory as FruitComboApplication.java
     ensure build system copies the fxml file to the build output path -->

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?scenebuilder-stylesheet fruitcombo.css?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="205.0" prefWidth="168.0" styleClass="layout" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="fruit.FruitComboController">
  <children>
    <ComboBox fx:id="fruitCombo" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="33.0" prefWidth="90.0" promptText="choose"/>
    <Label id="fruitSelectorLabel" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="10.0" styleClass="bold-label" text="Fruit Selector" />
    <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="62.0" prefHeight="134.0" prefWidth="140.0" spacing="8.0">
      <children>
        <StackPane id="selected-fruit-frame" minHeight="100.0" minWidth="118.0" prefHeight="108.0" prefWidth="140.0">
          <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="orangeImage" fitHeight="91.99999237060547" fitWidth="122.66666035739114" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
              <image>
                <Image url="http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2011/03/10/orange_iStock_000001331357X_540x405.jpg" preserveRatio="false" smooth="false" />
              </image>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView fx:id="pearImage" fitHeight="93.0" fitWidth="124.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
              <image>
                <Image url="http://smoothiejuicerecipes.com/pear.jpg" preserveRatio="false" smooth="false" />
              </image>
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView fx:id="appleImage" fitHeight="93.0" fitWidth="124.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" visible="false">
              <image>
                <Image url="http://uhallnyu.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/green-apple.jpg" preserveRatio="false" smooth="false" />
              </image>
            </ImageView>
          </children>
        </StackPane>
        <Label fx:id="selectedFruit" textAlignment="CENTER" />
      </children>
    </VBox>
  </children>
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@fruitcombo.css" />
  </stylesheets>
</AnchorPane>
```

*FruitComboController.java*

```
package fruit;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

/** JavaFX fxml controller for fruit combo fxml demo application. */
public class FruitComboController implements Initializable {

  @FXML // fx:id="appleImage"
  private ImageView appleImage; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

  @FXML // fx:id="fruitCombo"
  private ComboBox<String> fruitCombo; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

  @FXML // fx:id="orangeImage"
  private ImageView orangeImage; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

  @FXML // fx:id="pearImage"
  private ImageView pearImage; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

  @FXML // fx:id="selectedFruit"
  private Label selectedFruit; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

  @Override // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
  public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {
    assert appleImage != null : "fx:id=\"appleImage\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'fruitcombo.fxml'.";
    assert fruitCombo != null : "fx:id=\"fruitCombo\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'fruitcombo.fxml'.";
    assert orangeImage != null : "fx:id=\"orangeImage\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'fruitcombo.fxml'.";
    assert pearImage != null : "fx:id=\"pearImage\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'fruitcombo.fxml'.";
    assert selectedFruit != null : "fx:id=\"selectedFruit\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'fruitcombo.fxml'.";

    // populate the fruit combo box with item choices.
    fruitCombo.getItems().setAll("Apple", "Orange", "Pear");

    // bind the selected fruit label to the selected fruit in the combo box.
    selectedFruit.textProperty().bind(fruitCombo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());

    // listen for changes to the fruit combo box selection and update the displayed fruit image accordingly.
    fruitCombo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
      @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> selected, String oldFruit, String newFruit) {
        if (oldFruit != null) {
          switch(oldFruit) {
            case "Apple": appleImage.setVisible(false); break;
            case "Orange": orangeImage.setVisible(false); break;
            case "Pear": pearImage.setVisible(false); break;
          }
        }
        if (newFruit != null) {
          switch(newFruit) {
            case "Apple": appleImage.setVisible(true); break;
            case "Orange": orangeImage.setVisible(true); break;
            case "Pear": pearImage.setVisible(true); break;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

*FruitComboApplication.java*

```
package fruit;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/** Main application class for fruit combo fxml demo application */
public class FruitComboApplication extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    stage.setTitle("Choices");
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("http://files.softicons.com/download/application-icons/pixelophilia-icons-by-omercetin/png/32/apple-green.png"));
    AnchorPane layout = FXMLLoader.load(
      new URL(FruitComboApplication.class.getResource("fruitcombo.fxml").toExternalForm())
    );
    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

Sample Program Output:

[image: Sample Program Output]

Comment: i see your code, but you injected in FXML.. i need something like that
<TableView fx:id="tablaAgencia">
    <columns>
       <TableColumn text="Identificador" fx:id="idCol">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="id" />
             </cellValueFactory>
       </TableColumn>
</TableView>

Comment: where my Model class can did match with CellValueFactory.. can i do the same with combo box?

Comment: I am trying to do something similar in a Tableview where I have a combobox in a tablecell. How can I access it like you did with the id?

Comment: @TravisTubbs Perhaps take a look into [ComboBoxTableCell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/ComboBoxTableCell.html) (though I haven't tried it in conjunction with FXML).  If you have further questions about ComboBoxes and TableViews, it would be best to ask a new question (you can link back to this question in your new question).