# how to move objects with JAVA JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I try to develop a java project for kids to develop myself. I'm not expecting a code, just examples or documentations about it.
The project, takes two  numbers and two different kind of fruits from combobox and it displays thoso fruits with matching via line. 
For example, the kid select 2 and 3 as a number and apple and orange as a fruit. The program shows 2 apples,there will be line among 2 apples and 3 oranges and there will be line among 3 oranges.  And the kid(user) can move the fruits via drag and drop.

How can i do that? I dont know even keywords to search on anywhere.Which libraries or methods i have to learn ?

Sorry for bad language
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> the kid select 2 and 3 as a number

- two JSpinners for numbers with one SpinnerNumberModel (you can to reduce range)
- or two JComboBoxes with integers in the model as the Items (you can to reduce range)

---

> apple and orange as a fruit.

- two JComboBoxes with Icon/ImageIcon in the model (see Oracle tutorial for working code example)
- or two JLists  with Icon/ImageIcon in the model (use the same methods as for JComboBox, Items in JComboBox are in JList)

---

> can move the fruits via drag and drop.

- use JList for this idea
- put generated fruits as Item to the model for the another JList (horizontal wrap), for DnD to read Oracle tutorial for working code example about DnD between two JList

---

> How can i do that? I dont know even keywords to search on
>   anywhere.Which libraries or methods i have to learn ?

- post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short runnable, compilable in the case that you will have any issue(s) with a.m. points, demostrated your progress

Comment: Thank you for clear explanations. May i disturb you for some questions when i try to develop it?

Comment: yes or not too, but generally you are two choices, 1. edit this question (can't be in radar for most of users here inc me), 2. (recommended) split that to three - four parts as a new questions wiht an SSCCE, then these parts can be answered by many users here

Answer (score 1):

You can use javaFX. It is much more easier to use than swing and have a modern appearance. There is also a scene builder for javaFX. You can directly place combo boxes or lines via this scene builder.

Comment: Thank you for  suggestion. I will search javaFX

Comment: See the JavaFX based [FruitComboApplication](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3062859) created for [Combo Box JavaFx with FXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032257/combo-box-javafx-with-fxml)